# C# analog for getBytes in java

Tags: c#, java, string

There is wonderful method which class String has in java called getBytes.
In C# it's also implemented in another class - Encoding, but unfortunately it returns array of unsigned bytes, which is a problem.

How is it possible to get an array of signed bytes in C# from a string?

Comment: By the way, Java also has it in the `Charset` class (together with `CharsetDecoder` and `CharsetEncoder`), and `String.getBytes()` is just a shortcut to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Encoding.GetBytes` but then convert the `byte[]` to an `sbyte[]` by using something like [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx). However, I'd *strongly* encourage you to use the unsigned bytes instead - work round whatever problem you're having with them instead of moving to signed bytes, which were frankly a mistake in Java to start with. The reason there's no built-in way of converting a string to a signed byte array is because it's rarely something you really want to be doing.

If you can tell us a bit about why the unsigned bytes are causing you a problem, we may well be able to help you with *that* instead.

Comment: is something like sbyte[] array1 = (sbyte[]) (Array) array2; correct? if array2 is byte[]?

Comment: @Sergey: No, you don't just cast between the two. You should create a new array and copy the contents from one to the other using `Buffer.BlockCopy`.